# Make a image fall when an image below it disappears

Tags: javascript, image

I am currently working on an app with a friend and we need to make it so that an image will fall when the image below it disappears. So it needs to like take the images place when it disappears. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: "jQuery animate", no? Or pick whatever transition library you prefer, although this can be done by hand (and at least partly with CSS3) as well.

Comment: If you apply the CSS display: none, it removes the item from the DOM, and it won't take up any room. If you apply the CSS visible: hidden, the item is still there taking up space, but it is not visible. If you are using visibility to hide the unwanted image, then you might try changing to display:none.,

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) would be a good starting point for this.  Presumably you're hiding the image with JavaScript to begin with, so add code to the same function that loops through all of the images above it and moves them down to fill the gap (possibly using [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)).

Are you sure you want to move the images down, though?  That will leave an odd blank space at the top of the screen, where there's no image left to fall from above.  Images "falling" upwards when the image above them vanishes would make more sense on most HTML pages.